# Lenovo thinkpad keeps disconnecting from wifi, but the icon shows connected

Tags: drivers, wireless, thinkpad, iwlwifi, disconnect

**Device**: Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (3rd generation) running Ubuntu 16.04

**Problem**: The wifi keeps disconnecting in my home network, which slightly weaker than the wifi at work. The wifi at work is more stable, still disconnects on occasion. At home however it disconnects repeatedly, every few seconds of connecting sometimes. My android phone however stays connected without problems.

**Description**: When it disconnects the wifi icon does not change, but the internet stops working in applications and browsing. If I disconnect and reconnect it works again for an amount of time before disconnecting again in this manner.

**Attempts**: Reading around solutions I've set IPv6 method to "Ignore" in network connections settings. This has had no effects, I am not sure at this point how to fix this issue.

Running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` gives:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: It might be a shot in the dark, but I had a similar situation at my home. In my case it turned out that the signal output level of my router is adjustable. My router was set to 25%. Using a Wifi signal analyzer I learned the router was set to channel 11, the same channel as the router (same type) of my neighbor (approx 15 meters away). His router, set to 100%, also channel 11, occasionally  interfered/suppressed mine.
I solved by finding another channel and raising the output to 50%.

Comment: @WillemK thanks for the suggestiong, unfortunately I can't configure the router in my situation (not my router), otherwise I'd try. It happens sometimes with the wifi at work as well, although my phone and macs don't have this issue with the wifi

Comment: Is the Wifi adapter easy accessible?  If so, make sure that the adapter itself is firmly in the socket and the 2 little connectors are firmly attached. If that does not help, then I am afraid I am out of ideas.

Comment: @WillemK you mean the hardware inside my laptop? In that case no, it's not easily accessible, but I think they are connected fine.

Also, I was able to access the router configuration page, how do I check which channel it is, and do you mean increasing the MTU value for increasing the output?

Comment: Buy another laptop then ...   ;-))

Comment: It works much better with other wifi signals, and flawlessly in the past using windows which it shipped with. I don't think the laptop hardware is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69250/discussion-between-willemk-and-wrahim).